# ASP.net MVC 4 images load locally but not online

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

So I am currently working on a website where the images are hosted in the following location.

www.website.com/resources/images/products/imagename.jpg

when I type in the following url this works.

localhost:50836/resources/images/products/imagename.jpg

The following doesn't work and gives me a 404 error

www.newurl.com/resources/images/products/imagename.jpg.

I have logged into the ftp to make sure that the images are there are in the order of:

projectname/resources/images/products/imagename.jpg

I am currently working on redoing their site, taking nothing from the old site except the images. On the new site I have put the resources folder in the same location. However when I try and view the image on the new site I get a 404 error. It is important that the images are in the same location because the images are used in other locations.

Comment: How us how you're setting up the source of those images in your HTML. It's most likely an error in the way you're setting up the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add the following code to the Web.config in order to allow the images to be accessed.

```
<bundle virtualPath="~/resources/sample" transform="System.Web.Optimization.JsMinify, System.Web.Optimization">
        <content>

        </content>
      </bundle>
```